# Как зарегистрировать Stasis app в Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

```
$>dialplan show in
[ Context 'in' created by 'pbx_config' ]
'0123456789' =>   1. NoOp()                                     [pbx_config]
                  2. Answer()                                   [pbx_config]
                  3. Stasis(myapp)                              [pbx_config]
                  4. Hangup()                                   [pbx_config]

$> pjsip show endpoint pnt
Endpoint:  pnt                                   Not in use    0 of inf
context                                           in

$>module show like  res_stasis
Module                         Description                               Use Count  Status      Support Level
res_stasis.so                  Stasis application support               12         Running              core
res_stasis_answer.so           Stasis application answer support        0          Running              core
res_stasis_device_state.so     Stasis application device state support  0          Running              core
res_stasis_playback.so         Stasis application playback support      0          Running              core
res_stasis_recording.so        Stasis application recording support     0          Running              core
res_stasis_snoop.so            Stasis application snoop support         0          Running              core
6 modules loaded
```

При поступлении вызова на контекст 'in' получаю:

```
res_stasis.c:1268 stasis_app_exec: Stasis app 'myapp' not registered
```

Asterisk 13.12.1

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось - для регистрации нужен клиент для WebSocket.

При присоединении клиента по адресу /ari/events?app=myapp&subscribeAll=true&api_key=usr:pwd активируется myapp.

Для управления каналом в диалплане необходимо вызвать Stasis(myapp) в нужном контексте.